# ionic 2 : Getting unsafe url error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, unsafe

I'm trying to open a whats'app link and I'm getting thus error :

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value SafeValue must use
(see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

here is my code :

```
<a href="{{surl}}">
<img src="assets/imgs/whatsapp.png" height=35px/></a>
```

and in the ts file here is what surl holds :

```
this.url = 'whatsapp://send?text=Hello World!&phone=+966'+this.phone
this.surl = this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.url);
```

the problem as you can tell is that I'm passing a variable to the url , but cordova won't trust it !
any ideas how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/angular2-warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-urlsafevalue-must-use-proper

Comment: @ChristianBenseler they say that I should wrap the entire url which is exactly what I did :(

Comment: What if you try by placing it directly in the view, like this:

`<a [href]="dom.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url)">`

Where `url` is set in the component code like `this.url = 'whatsapp://send?text=Hello World!&phone=+966' + this.phone;`

Comment: actually I solved it by `<a [href]="surl"></a>` where `surl` is the safe url , and it worked ! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by `<a [href]="surl"></a>` where `surl` is the safe url , and it worked !