# Dynamic colour range based on value

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a dynamic colour range so I can display some data. For example, if I have the values `[1.0, 1.6, 2.3, 2.9, 3.5, 4.2, 4.7, 5.0]` then I would like to be able to set e.g. `1.0` as the colour green, `2.5` as the colour yellow and `5.0` as the colour red, resulting in something like the screenshot shown below

[image: Colour range example from Excel]

And example in Angular is shown here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z32yhk?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

I do not *just* want to have a range from green to red for example, but it could be from yellow to purple. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Create and share any plunker or sample first.

Comment: @RohanFating I don't know how to implement what I'm asking, that's why I'm asking in the first place, and I think my post is clear enough without a plunker.

Comment: Though it is clear with your requirement, we appreciate if you atleast provide skeleton structure code so that we don't need to work from scratch. Respect others time as well.

Comment: To which kind of element should the background-color be affected ? A div, a table cell, ... ?

Comment: @Mr_Green I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

I will provide you the value generating function which you can `*ngFor` or do anything with it as per your need.

I am considering `hsl` type colors to give different colors here.

- Base color value: `hsl(40, 55%, 95%)`
- High color value : `hsl(140, 55%, 95%)`

---

```
attachColors() {
    const x = [1.0, 1.6, 2.3, 2.9, 3.5, 4.2, 4.7, 5.0];    // Your data
    const baseValue = 40;                                  // Base color value (red)
    const highValue = 140;                                 // Highest color value (green)
    const max = Math.max.apply(null, x);                   // Max value in your data
    const min = Math.min.apply(null, x);                   // Min value in your data
    let y = x.map(v => { 
              return {
                 value: v, 
                 color: (baseValue + (((v - min)/(max - min)) * (highValue - baseValue)))
              }
            });

    // Now "y" holds your data + color value for it
    return y;
}
```

Now in your template, you can probably do like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let d of attachColors()" [style.backgroundColor]="'hsl(' + d.color + ', 55%, 95%)'"></li>
```

Comment: I tried getting this to work, but it doesn't actually apply the style. As a side note: use `const` instead of `let`.

Comment: The template example I provided is not a tested one. I tested the function which returning the values as required.

Comment: @Esoemah Doing like this should work.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663363/1577396

Comment: I fixed it, but the colours aren't really correct for some reason.

Comment: Oh nice. Well, you can play with the range i.e base and high values. Or even may try to change other params of `hsl` color.

Answer (score 0):

A new little example:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>value</th>
        </tr>
         <tr [ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.'+ n.toString().split('.')[1]  +')' }" *ngFor="let n of numbers">
          <td >{{n}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  numbers:float[] = [1.1,1.3,1.4,1.9];
  constructor(){
    for(let n of this.numbers){
      console.log();
    }
  }


  //[ngClass]="{'red': n == 1, 'green': n == 2, 'orange': n == 3
      //          , 'pink': n == 4, 'blue': n == 5}"

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ACuGatopbzFQERgRdZp9

Can you calculate the differents colours you want of any range of numbers(1,2,3,4,5..) and calculate & diferenciate with the opacity.

Comment: I said dynamic, not static. You are literally manually assigning a colour to a discrete value... what about `1.2` or `2.4` for example? I want them to be different colours than `1` and `2` respectively.