# domSanitizer SafeStyle not working Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im aware there are similar questions like so.. [domSanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868) and [WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url/38663363#38663363but) I have done what has been said in those and I cant seem to get it to work...

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="item?.fields?.asset[0]?.fields?.backgroundImage" class="program-item_background" [style.background]=backgroundImage></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class ProgramItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, Sanitizer {
    @Input() item: Entry<any>; // Program Item getting passed down from the parent        
    backgroundImage: SafeStyle;

constructor(
    private sanitization: DomSanitizer
) { }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.backgroundImage = this.safeStyle(this.item.fields.asset[0].fields.backgroundImage.fields.file.url);
}

safeStyle(url){
    return this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`'url(${url})'`);
}
```

I'm also getting this error in the console.. [image]

but I think thats because it couldnt find the backgroundImage oninit.. due to it being pulled in from an external api

any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

**EDIT**

I have also tried this...

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.backgroundImage = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`'url(${this.item.fields.asset[0].fields.backgroundImage.fields.file.url})'`);
}
```

but that doesnt seem to working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work around instead of using a sanitized url I just used `[ngStyle]` like so

```
<div *ngIf="item?.fields?.asset[0]?.fields?.backgroundImage" class="program-item_background" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + this.item.fields.asset[0].fields.backgroundImage.fields.file.url + ') 50% no-repeat'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Event though your item has `?` in the template, you still have `this.item` in the class. Which means, you need to make sure this.item always exist. That's why you are getting that error.

Comment: this.item does exist (just added it to the question) but because it comes in dynamically when the page first loads its not available but after 2 seconds its avaliable hence why the call is made on `ngOnChanges`