# Multiple transform properties not working in template

Tags: angular

I want to build a very simple editor which allows a user to transform a background image.

For this purpose I am setting `transform` like this:

```xml
<img [style.transform]="'translate(50%,50%) rotate(45deg)'">
```

The problem is that if I set both, `translate`and `rotate`, the style is not getting applied. I can set them alone but not together.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jklrg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: @trichetriche That's *one line* of HTML but [there you go](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jklrg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) ..

Comment: And does that *one line of HTML* tells us what you provide for `left, top, rotate` ? Thank you, I'll take a look at it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url

Comment: Firefox console shows this log entry: WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value translate(50%,50%) rotate(45deg) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Comment: The console showed a warning that I googled. It seems to be solvable by using [ngStyle] instead of [style.*]

Comment: @ShamPooSham That works indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @trichetriche I'm sorry for my snap - it's not a particularly good day for me today.

Comment: No problem ! Other people provided you with an answer, as you can see in the console your issue is with the sanitization of your strings. You should be able to find resources in the documentation with the given URL, or as @ShamPooSham suggested, in another question. Hope you resolve your issue !

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks. Yes, it works with `ngStyle`  as suggested (`[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'translate(' + imgLeft + '%, ' + imgTop + '%) rotate(' + imgRotate * 90 +'deg)'}"`)