# How can I display image encoded in base64 format in Angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, base64, angular6

I struggle with a problem associated with Angular 6 and displaying image encoded in base64 format. Any ideas why code shown below doesn't display image?

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of this.UploaderService.tableImageRecognition.dataRows">
<img src="{{this.hello}}" />
```

ts:

```
this.hello = "data:image/png;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA..."
```

While code shown below works properly and displays picture?

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of this.UploaderService.tableImageRecognition.dataRows">
<!--<img src="data:image/png;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA..."/>
```

`this.hello` is assigned in the constructor just for test purpose. I create it in this way `this.hello = 'data:image/png;base64, ' + this.UploaderService.imageRecognitionRowsData[0].toString()` My main goal is to display `imageRecognitionRowsData` in this loop `<tr *ngFor="let row of this.UploaderService.tableImageRecognition.dataRows">`. So for first iteration I would display image `imageRecognitionRowsData[0]` then during next iteration image `imageRecognitionRowsData[1]` etc. The length of `this.UploaderService.tableImageRecognition.dataRows` is always the same as `this.UploaderService.imageRecognitionRowsData` When I add `<p>{{this.hello}}</p>` I get the same string in html.
I have no idea what is wrong. I tried also with `this.hello2 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.hello);`, `this.hello2 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.hello);`, `<img [src]="this.hello" />` etc. but nothing works. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't use "this" to refer the variables defined in the component "ts" file. Remove "this" may solve your problem.

Please Review this stackbliz Fiddle. Look inside the app component to see the implementation.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9n9np)

Comment: I get warnings `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value data:image/png;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA` and error `Failed to load resource: unsupported URL`

Comment: Yes, it is a browser security warning, please follow this link to resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url

Comment: I tried everything - displaying it as a `string`, as a `SafeResourceUrl` variable, I tried to use `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`,`bypassSecurityTrustStyle`, `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${this.UploaderService.test})`);`, I tried different ways of displaying this in HTML: `<img src="this.UploaderService.test2 ">, <img [src]="this.UploaderService.test2">` also with test variable. I have no idea what else can I try. If you have any suggestions just write and I will test it. I struggle with this problem for a very long time.

Comment: can you post one of the base64 url for me? So that I can reproduce this?

Comment: Do you mean my image encoded in base64 that I have in a hello2 variable?

Comment: Yes, because I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: Guess I have resolved it, I have update the stackblitz, please follow the link to see the solution.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9n9np

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me when working with base64 images.

HTML:

```
<img [src]="currVerifiedLoanOfficerPhoto">
```

Component:

```
this.currVerifiedLoanOfficerPhoto = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + (this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(item) as any).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `this` in html templates in Angular. All the variables/member methods are resolved on class by default. Access the variables directly as follows:

```
<img [src]="hello" />
```

Comment: The image is still not displayed.

Comment: there must be other issues as well. Debug your logic.

Comment: I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` `http://localhost:4200/hello` but I am sure that I don't send request to `http://localhost:4200/hello`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It does not require any additional transformations. It is as simples as adding the `src` directives for base64:

> ```
> <img
>   [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageAsBase64"
> />
> ```

Assuming you have the `imageAsBase64` variable on the .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

```
convertToImage() {
const img = new Image();
img.src = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}`;
this.imageUrl = img.src;}
```

Pass your base64 code in the image variable