# Angular style: add dynamically a background-image with an overlay

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

So I have an array with the names of images files. I use Angular and this array is a property of my component class.

```
const backgroundImages = [
  'gym-background.jpg',
'home-background-2.jpg',
  'pt-background.jpeg'
];
```

I want to use these images as background-image of a card. I use Angular and have the following code in my template

```
<div class="card" [style.background-image]="determineBackground()">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h3 class="card-title">{{workout.name}}</h3>
    <fa-icon class="card-enlarge" [icon]="['fas', 'search-plus']"></fa-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, this will trigger determineBackground() in the component. This function returns the following string:

```
  determineBackground() {
    const chosenImage = this.backgroundImgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.backgroundImgs.length)];

    return `linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(#000,.5), rgba(#000,.5)), url("/assets/images/${chosenImage}")`;
  }
```

So, I return the value for the `background-image` style property. `Math.floor(Math.random() * this.backgroundImgs.length)` returns a value between 0 and 2 to randomly decide which image to use as background. Unfortunately it doesn't work this way, I do not see a background-image even though const chosenImage is a valid value. Could you guys help me see why?

> Complete component ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'workout-list-item',
  templateUrl: './workout-list-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workout-list-item.component.scss']
})
export class WorkoutListItemComponent implements OnInit {

  backgroundImgs =  ['gym-background.jpg','home-background-2.jpg','pt-background.jpeg'];

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  determineBackground() {
    const chosenImage = this.backgroundImgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.backgroundImgs.length)];
return `linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(#000,.5), rgba(#000,.5)), url("/assets/images/${chosenImage}")`;
 }
}
```

**Updated code**

component

```
export class WorkoutListItemComponent implements OnInit {

  backgroundImgs = backgroundImages;
  chosenImage: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
    this.chosenImage = this.backgroundImgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.backgroundImgs.length)];
    console.log('choseImage', this.chosenImage);
  }
}
```

template

```
<div
  class="card"
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': chosenImage ? 'linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(#000,.5), rgba(#000,.5)), url(\'/assets/images/' + chosenImage + '\')' : ''}"
>
  <div class="card-header">
    <h3 class="card-title">{{workout.name}}</h3>
    <fa-icon class="card-enlarge" [icon]="['fas', 'search-plus']"></fa-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the error log, you should have something about sanitizing in there

Comment: @Drenai yeah I changed it and now the HTML is:

Comment: <div class="card" [style.background-image]="'linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(#000,.5), rgba(#000,.5)), url(\'/assets/images/' + chosenImage + '\')'">

Comment: And still no background-image, but like @Vega said I did get the sanitizing error.

Comment: Then look up for that error message in SO, the same issu should have been resolved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38593515/5468463

Comment: Thanks Vega, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow on from my comment: Calling functions from the template will cause the change detector to loop through the function dozens of times - use `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` and set a public property on the component instead, and then bind to that

Use the following `ngStyle` approach in the template to avoid the `url` sanitization problems without the hassle

```
[ngStyle]="{
                'background-image': (chosenImage) ? 'url(' + chosenImage + ')' : ''         
            }"
```

Comment: It's still not working unfortunately. I'll update my code on top.

Comment: So it works when I just enter the URL as background image, but with the linear gradient it's not possible. I kinda do need that gradient though because otherwise I can't see my text on top

Comment: I kinda found an alternative to add overlay to background image: I added box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px rgba(255,0,150,0.1); to the card element and that has the same effect.