# How to resolver url sanitizer warning in angular?

Tags: angular, image, sanitize

I have this call inside my html file:

**profile.html**

```
<div mat-card-avatar *ngIf="imgResult" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + imgResult + ')' }" class="avatar">
  <mat-icon *ngIf="!imgResult">person</mat-icon>
</div>
```

My component is like this:

**profile.component.ts**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

...

```
  picture: File;
  imgResult: any;
```

...

```
constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }
```

...

```
  onChange(event) {
    this.picture= event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.picture);
    reader.onload = (ev: any) => {
      this.imgResult = ev.target.result;
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.imgResult);
    };
  }
```

The picture load is working as expected but, I can't stop the `sanitizing unsafe URL value` warning.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the sanitizer correctly but not using the result value. Try this instead:

```
reader.onload = (ev: any) => {
  const trustedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${ev.target.result})`);
  this.imgResult = trustedUrl;
};
```

And use this in html file instead:

```
[style.background-image]="imgResult"
```

This question is already answered at this topic: [WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url)

Comment: Thanks @David but It didn't work. If I use this code that you suggested me, the picture isn't loaded and the warning persists.

Comment: Can you try using the method bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl instead?

Comment: I tried. But the issues persist: not loading the picture and warning message (still the same)

Comment: I have found this. If you check the most upvoted answer it is quite similar to yours. Let's see if that does it, it would actually make sense for it to be a style resource:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url

Comment: thank you so much! I've spent a lot of time during today on searching a topic which could help me and didn't find this one, even during posting this question. Now it's working. I'll keep this question only as an alternative for new searches and post the link and details in your answer.