# How to send image in put request using angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, file-upload

The api data is like this

```
{
    "id": 11,    
    "About_Me": "Male working for ----" ,
    "About_Me_Photo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/personal/aboutme/2021-09-06/15-50-03/1.jpg",        
}
```

For sending the data, service.ts is

```
individual1(About_Me){    
      console.log("mf");    
      let url = this.mf+"rajperson/11/";;    
      var dec = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('token')));
          
         this.hdrs=new HttpHeaders({    
            Authorization: "Token " + dec,    
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",    
            Accept: "application/json",    
          })    
            return this.http.put(url,{About_Me:About_Me,},{headers:this.hdrs});
```

The code is working fine for data but for image i passed the path which doesn't work. Can any one help me on updating the image using put request.

Comment: Try to convert the image to base64 string and then pass it to the api and then convert it back to image in api

Comment: please show complete work including HTML there is not enough here to properly answer the question. My presumption is you will need to use santizeHTML pipe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url)

Answer (score 0):

Implemented by converting the image to base64. The code is as follows

On page.ts :

```
myimage: Observable<any>;

 onChange($event: Event) {
   const file = ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
   this.convertToBase64(file);
 }

 convertToBase64(file: File) {
   this.myimage = new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber<any>) => {
     this.readFile(file, subscriber);
   });
 }
 readFile(file: File, subscriber: Subscriber<any>) {
   const filereader = new FileReader();
   filereader.readAsDataURL(file);
   filereader.onload = () => {
     subscriber.next(filereader.result);
     this.user.individual1(filereader.result).subscribe((res:any)=>{
        alert("Refresh to find the changes");
     })
     subscriber.complete();
   };
   filereader.onerror = (error) => {
     subscriber.error(error);
     subscriber.complete();
   };
 }
```

On service.ts :

```
   individual1(photo){
      console.log("mf");
      let url = this.mf+"rajperson/11/";;
      var dec = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('token')));
      //dec = "353f4409296eb7b29f1d65ea4304c6fe6f358dcf"
         this.hdrs=new HttpHeaders({
            Authorization: "Token " + dec,
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            Accept: "application/json",
          })
          console.log(dec)
          console.log((localStorage.getItem('token')))
            return this.http.put(url,{photo:photo,},{headers:this.hdrs});

    }
```

On page.html :

```
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" />

<div *ngIf="myimage">
  <img [src]="myimage | async" width="200px" height="200px" alt="" />
</div>
```