# How to present an externally hosted image from a dataset on Angular

Tags: html, angular, mongodb

So currently, I'm displaying info from a dataset on my angular front end. For each entry in the dataset, I'm showing the name, address, rating, and image. I'm having some trouble displaying the image, however. The image is an external HTML link stored in 'html_attributions' which is stored within the object 'photos'.

[image]

Below is the code I currently have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div *ngFor="let place of place_list | async">
                <div class="card text-white bg-secondary mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        {{ place.name }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Address:
                        {{ place.formatted_address }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        Rating:
                        {{ place.rating }}
                    </div>
                    <img src = "{{place.photos}}">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
 </div>
```

I'm getting this error:
[object%20Object]:1 GET http://localhost:4200/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

I've also tried {{place.html_attributions}}, which hasn't worked. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
// code above
<ng-container *ngFor="let photo of place?.photos">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let htmlAttribution of photo?.html_attributions">
         <img src="{{htmlAttribution}}">
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
// code below
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm now getting this error in the console: 



trails.component.html:50 WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110135647500030257709">A Google User</a>

unsafe:<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110135647500030257709">A Google User</a>:1          GET unsafe:<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110135647500030257709">A Google User</a>

Comment: I assume your primary query is to get the nested url values to be shown in the template. So that part is completed. Now you are facing external link sanitization. For that, checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url